# which is difference between "getConstructor()" and "getConstructor((Class<?>[]) null)"?

Tags: java

I try to understand this difference with this example:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
public class ClassDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     try {
        // returns the Constructor object of the public constructor
        //Class cls[] = new Class[] { String.class };
        Constructor c = String.class.getConstructor();
        System.out.println(c);
     }
     catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
     } 
   }
}
```

I get this result:

> public java.lang.String()

In this example, if I replace:

```
Constructor c = String.class.getConstructor();
```

by:

```
Constructor c = String.class.getConstructor((Class<?>[]) null);
```

I get the same result...

why and what is the subtlety ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They do exactly the same thing.

When you call `String.class.getConstructor()`, you actually have an empty array of `Class<?>` as an argument. This is equal to calling it using `(Class<?>[]) null`, which can be seen by checking the way it compares the type parameters to the ones in the constructor:

```
private static boolean arrayContentsEq(Object[] a1, Object[] a2) {
    if (a1 == null) {
        return a2 == null || a2.length == 0;
    }

    if (a2 == null) {
        return a1.length == 0;
    }

    if (a1.length != a2.length) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
        if (a1[i] != a2[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

As you can see, empty arrays and nulls are treated as equals. You could also call it using `new Class<?>[0]` as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference as it is the same method, [Class.getConstructor(Class... parameterTypes)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor-java.lang.Class...-).
It is allowed to call this method without parameters. These are called [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html#varargs).

Answer (score 1):

Just read the manual.

`public java.lang.reflect.Constructor getConstructor(java.lang.Class[] parameterTypes)`

It takes types of constructor parameters. It's needed in case constructor is overloaded.

Answer (score 0):

if you write

```
    System.out.println(String.class.getConstructor(String.class));
```

output
public java.lang.String(java.lang.String)